# Using Raspberry Command line editor 'Nano' vs LeafPad to edit a text file string. Causes php to not be able to read string correctly

Tags: php, html, mysql, command-line, raspberry-pi

When using Nano as a text editor on a raspberry pi to edit a text file, php file doesn't seem to be able to query the variable correctly in SQL. However, when editing the file using LeafPad editor built into the Pi, the php file outputs the query correctly.

Any thoughts? I initially thought it would be character encoding issue but this does not seem to be the case. I checked the php encoding with `echo mb_detect_encoding($str);` and found it is in ASCII and did not change when I edited in the command line editor.

Any help or suggestion would be appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

By default nano use the system encoding of the operating system. I checked this. On a raspian installation that would be UTF-8 by default. So if you did not change it, your php texts are encoded with UTF-8. As you investigated, your php uses ASCII to decode. That could cause the problem. But this could cause the problem only if you use non ASCII characters (öäüè...) in your code, otherwise ASCII and UTF-8 do not differ. You can check the encoding of the text file with the file command.

```
pi@raspberrypi ~ $ file <xyz>.php
```

If the output is

```
  <xyz>.php: UTF-8 Unicode text
```

you can be sure that there are non ASCII in your php script.

But perhaps it's not the php that caused the problem. You wrote that, your SQL did not work. Then the encoding of your database may be e.g ISO 8859-1 and the SQL string was encoded in UTF-8.

Comment: I have check that my SQL database is in UTF -8

Editing the text file(using sublime text editor) on macbook and hosting the webpage on my mac did not cause any issue .

However on raspberry pi editing the text file with the build in command line tool seems to be the issue.

Hmm alright will give it a try and check on the encoding.